# Binding a list in @RequestParam includes square brackets

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, data-binding, collections

When I pass a list `("EN", "IT")` as a `@RequestParam`, it binds it as `(["EN", "IT"])`. So the first element is `(["EN`, and the second one is `"IT"]`.
How can you explain this?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/countRequests", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<BigInteger> getCountRequests(
   @RequestParam("languages") List<String> languages)
```

Comment: I passed ("EN", "IT") and no include square. it binds as first ("EN", second "IT")  because it evaluates separate item with the comma.  spring 4.0.1 release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `[]` syntax to pass arrays (or lists).

Try to execute your request this way:

```
/countRequests?languages=EN,IT
```

This way Spring MVC should bind your parameter correctly. Take a try.

Another way is to use this syntax:

```
/countRequests?languages[]=EN&languages[]=IT
```

Comment: @davioooh, What about maps? What is the syntax to pass a Map<String,String> for instance as a @RequestParam?

Comment: @davioooh any idea how could one get this working for a 2d input that should be parsed as `List<List<String>>`